# Android drawer effect

Tags: android, drawer

I want to achieve an effect:

**Page A** displays list. A button is on the top of page A.
On click this button, the **Page B** will be displayed.
The **Page A** will be push to `right side`, but `not extrusion`.

**Page A** still display `10%`, but `not hidden`.

Comment: Looks like a variation of the Sliding Drawer or a Expandable Panel. Google it.

Comment: Thanks, I found HorizontalScrollView, it resolved for me.